# Is there an alternative to ICQ?

Tags: software-recommendation

I don't mean any chat program that supports ICQ, like pidgin or empathy.

If there is one fully written just for [ICQ](http://www.icq.com/en) in Ubuntu/Linux.

**Edited**: The reason I want an alternative application, that is for some other programs like pidgin or empathy ICQ is just a part of the project. I want a full program just for ICQ.

Comment: why would you want one, if empathy has all the features?

Comment: First thing I don't like it much, Second, The new Icq does not provide Icq number when signing up, and empathy still give me the option to sign using the Icq number. 
read here : [known Issues](http://www.icq.com/download/icq/knownIssues/en)
Also Why not to know if there is an alternative:)

Comment: is ICQ still being used on a large scale?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_messaging#User_base) In 2010 Icq had 50M active users. for Me , I use it maybe everyday , Also it is coming in [linux](http://www.icq.com/download/linux/en) ,but for 32bits and I can't install it!

Comment: ICQ IS USED, but mainly in Russia :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Icq is now available in beta Version:**

[image]

**Installation:**

**For 32-bit:**

- Install [Adobe Air](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/).
- Download and install [ICQ](http://www.icq.com/download/linux/en).

**For 64-bit:**

- Follow the instructions to install *Adobe Air* for 64-bit:   [How do I install Adobe AIR?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47560/how-do-i-install-adobe-air-64bit)
- Download and Install [ICQ](http://www.icq.com/download/linux/en)

Comment: Can you click on the download button ?

Comment: @binarylife Nope.

Comment: The official ICQ client for Linux is an Adobe AIR app, you need to have the adobe-air package (from the Partner repository) installed. If so, clicking on the download button will launch the AIR Application Install utility.

Comment: Sadly I can't use it on 11.04 64bit

Comment: @Extender , Now you can :)