# How do I install Adobe AIR?

Tags: 11.04, adobe-air

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Adobe AIR?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87447/how-can-i-install-adobe-air)

I found some links, but they all seem a bit unsure, so I'm wondering if it is possible, and looking for simple (if possible) instructions.

Comment: I have had past success in installing Adobe Air under Ubuntu amd64.  I do not recall of the details, but I had no issue.  Please note that this was accomplished with Ubuntu releases prior to 11.04.  I will look around for the 'How To' I followed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this link. I tried it and it worked fine on my Ubuntu 11.04 64 bit installation... [Install Adobe AIR on 64 Bit Ubuntu 11.04](http://www.jamesward.com/2010/10/14/install-adobe-air-on-64-bit-ubuntu-10-10/)

Comment: This is certainly a much easier method of installation than what I recall having gone through.